# Batch remove Remove quote in text file and first line of data

Tags: batch-file, cmd, quote

I am writing a code to accomplish a few things:

1. Add date to the end of a text file
2. Remove " from the text file
3. Remove first line from text file (Header)

The test file looks like this:

```
Header
"Data Line 1
Data Line 2"
```

So far I have this which works for the first item:

````
```

@echo off


for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%

set stamp=%MM%%DD%%YYYY%
move "C:\test\*.csv" "C:\test\test_%stamp%.txt"

```
````

Comment: Please show a real example of one of your files. `cmd` can be quite picky when it comes to formatting or special chars. To clarify: do you want to add the date to the file *name* or the file's *content*?

Comment: Adding the date is done. I just need to do that in conjunction with the other two items. I'm looking to delete my first line of data that will be a header called "Extract" and the next lines have client information. The txt file was a csv and when converting add (") through out the document.

Comment: If you have control over the converting part, you really should fix the issue there. Fixing it later means to read the file(s) line by line, process each line and write to a new file. Depending on the exact content, this could be difficult.

Comment: Quotes serve an important purpose in CSV files. Removing them can corrupt the data. Any value that contains `"`, `,` or `<newline>` must be quoted. `"` literal values must be doubled. It is always valid to quote any CSV value even if it is not required.

Comment: Using SSRS I can not export directly to text. I must download/file share a CSV and then convert it to a text file. In that conversion the quote is added. I'm not converting back to CSV so I will not need the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set stamp=%MM%%DD%%YYYY%
for %%a in ("c:\test\*.csv") do (
  (for /f "usebackq skip=1 delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do (
    set "line=%%b"
    echo !line:"=!
  ))>"C:\test\test_%%~na_%stamp%.txt"
)
```

Completely untested and may produce unwanted results depending on the exact file contents (which you didn't show us).

Comment: Thank you for this. It did remove the first line of data but it added -"line = *"- to every line of text after that. I striped this line from the text file as an example.

    "line=5004123456789      191111200308Watkins        Jacob       
    Q1907151911181YYS                1906264.00 1500   500.00 500.00             123 
    Green Park Drive          Deltona              AK367295412078761N                                                                       
    4461233   RAMI      712128                           "

Comment: The additional `line=` issue should be solved with my edited code (5 minutes before your comment). Please try again

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks. Everything seems to be running as expected.